# Relation Hopf categories and categorified quantum groups

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, quantum-groups

In the paper [Hopf Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405183) Crane and Frenkel gave a definition of a Hopf category, which they considered as a categorification of a quantum group. Categorifications of quantum groups have later been defined by Rouquier in [2-Kac-Moody groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.5023) and Khovanov and Lauda in their series of papers [KL1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4121), [KL2](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2080) and [KL3](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.3250). The latter is in fact a 2-category not a category, where the former seems to be representation categories of something called trialgebras.

Are there any results on the relation of the two notions of categorification of quantum groups?